# Assign boolean value's to multiple properties in Swift

Tags: swift, boolean

```
var a:Bool
var b:Bool
var c:Bool = true

a = !c

a = b = !c
```

In the above example a = !c works fine, while the a = b = !c gives compile time error.

Is this simple syntax not supported in Swift 3.0? What could be a better way for this line of code.

Comment: The gist of it is "the assignment operator in Swift does not itself return a value"

Comment: If you're desperate to do the assignment on one line, you could use tuple syntax, but you'd still have to specifically assign each value:

(a, b, c) = (true, true, true)

Comment: For the joy of it, an obscure alternative approach would be: `b = (a = !c, a).1`.